# MongoDB upsert fields of objects in an array

Tags: mongodb, upsert

I am trying to do an upsert containing fields of objects in an array.

As an example, this is the data that I want to upsert:

```json
{
  'myarray.0.myfield': 'myvalue'
}
```

If the entry already exists this works fine. But if the entry doesn't exists it creates an object `{ "myarray": { "0": { "myfield" : "myvalue" } } }` instead of an array `{ "myarray": [{ "myfield": "myvalue"}] }`

Is there a way to tell MongoDB to create an array and not an object?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `{ $push: { myarray : { "myfield" : "myvalue" } }}`

Comment: @Jdsans it doesn't update a given index. Maybe I should go with the key-value instead of array option...

Comment: If you are looking to update the document at a specific array position provided you already know the position then you would use the $position operator. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/

`{ $push: { "myfield": { $each: [ "value1", "value2" ], $position: <num> } } }`

Comment: The issue is that this won't work with an upsert operation since the entry might be created from scratch.

Comment: Which operation are you using to modify or update?

Comment: The library in my project uses updateMany